# making object movement smooth in a java applet

Tags: java

Hi friends i'm trying to write a simple program that will move a little square right,left,up, and down smoothly.

As is, the square will indeed move in the four directions but there is a noticeable delay when trying to change the direction of the square. I plan on eventually writing a little game similar to the 'brick' game but in order to do that my object has to move smoothly. Can someone give me some advice on how to achieve this?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class FutureGame extends Applet implements KeyListener{

int deltax; 
int deltay;

public void init(){

    deltax = 0;
    deltay = 0;
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

    if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_RIGHT){
        deltax = deltax +10;
    }

    if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_LEFT){
        deltax = deltax - 10;
    }

    if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_UP){
        deltay = deltay - 10;
    }

    if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_DOWN){
        deltay = deltay +10;
    }
    this.repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawRect(deltax, deltay, 10, 10);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your thread(games's main calculations) sleeping/waiting time is very small, your key-listeners could not catch your keystrokes within that small time. Make those thread waiting times bigger and try again. I mean the things in try-catch blocks.

You are drawing directly. Use buffering/doublebuffering.

```
Changing the buffer is much more faster than changing the contents of screen.
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try double buffering

Comment: I tried the double buffering and it didn't really help. I'm not sure what you mean by my thread waiting time, i don't have any explicit threads in the program..  Did you mean to add some Thread.sleep() in my keypressed method?

Comment: then what is your main()'s sleep time. This is an applet. Where are you making your calculation(game engine) waiting? You must have one(to let your key-listener catch the keystrokes)

Comment: It must be whatever the default time is, i'm honestly not sure

Comment: where is your start() and destroy() methods?

Comment: I haven't used any. This is just a simple program to try to get the moving smooth. Will i need those methods for this?

Comment: For the buffering and a steady FPS, yes

Comment: You are just drawing when your keys are pressed am i right? if your keyboard sends 200 signals per second, you cannot draw that fast without some serious libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use paintComponent() as drawing method, then cast Graphics g to Graphics2D - make it more "Swingy", and last but not least follow the code as in java2s.com site [java2s.com - Advanced Graphics - Smooth Moves](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/SmoothMoves.htm)